# AWS Amplify PubSub is keeping previous user subscription active even after SignOut

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, mqtt, aws-amplify, publish-subscribe

Unfortunately i discovered a faulty behavior of AWS Amplify PubSub.

Lets say user A has the authority to subscribe through PubSub library (got it's permission by manually attaching iot policy for the specific user's Cognito identity id).
He is receiving successfully messages from AWS IoT and it's time for him to SignOut (without unsubscribe first) for an other user to SignIn from the same computer.

So user B SignIn but he doesn't have authority to subscribe (no policy has been attached to his Cognito identity id). Unfortunately Amplify will keep the subscription active from the previous user and the Non-authorized user B will receive the mqtt data successfully until he reload the page. Of course the opposite stands too (user A can't recieve cause previously logged in user B didn't had authority to subscribe)

I managed to solve it by running unsubscribe function on `componentWillUnmount()` but i'm not satisfied with this approach.

Do you think i'm doing something wrong? I'm subscribing with

```
PubSub.subscribe('myTopic').subscribe({
    next: data => console.log('Message received', data),
    error: error => console.error(error),
    complete: () => console.log('Done'),
});
```

on redux-action and simply dispatch the message on `next: data =>`

Comment: Ah I understand the issue except one part - `user A can't recieve cause previously logged in user B didn't had authority to subscribe` can you expand on this a bit more please? User A can't then receive messages even after user B signs out?

Comment: Sure, let me explain better. As i said User A has the authority to subscribe to mqtt updates and User B has not. 

Let's say: User B sign-in-> can't successfully subscribe cause he doesnt has the authority ->decide to sing-out-> User A sing-in from the same pc-> can't successfully subscribe too even having the authority except if he reloads the page first.
So i think the prev subscription is getting hold in a way, i don't know what to think

Comment: Understood - try creating an issue on the AWS Amplify GitHub page.

Comment: I will, but i can't see much responses there though

Comment: If you have a minimal reproducible example attached, they definitely will triage and get back to you :)